# dotnet restore command failed in azure cloud shell

Tags: azure-cloud-shell

"dotnet restore" command failed like below. How can I resolve this?

```
kim@Azure:~/clouddrive$ ls
lll
kim@Azure:~/clouddrive$ dotnet new console --name test
Content generation time: 1189.1072 ms
The template "Console Application" created successfully.
kim@Azure:~/clouddrive$ cd test
kim@Azure:~/clouddrive/test$ dotnet restore
  Restoring packages for /usr/kim/clouddrive/test/test.csproj...
  Generating MSBuild file 
/usr/kim/clouddrive/test/obj/test.csproj.nuget.g.props.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.1/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : The file 
'/usr/kim/clouddrive/test/obj/test.csproj.nuget.g.props' already exists. 
[/usr/kim/clouddrive/test/test.csproj]
kim@Azure:~/clouddrive/test$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dotnet restore` will work in your home directory (it is also persisted). So create your project in ~/dotnet would work.

clouddrive folder is a direct smb mount with 777 permission, it appears that dotnet restore doesn't like it. Similar problem for git. So only store your files that need upload / download there (scripts, executable etc), but not project.